# Regex (in Python) for matching whitespace that is preceeded by a even number of quotation marks

Tags: python, regex

I need match the whitespace (for re.split) but only when it is outside of quotation marks.
The method I'm trying is so long as there are an even number of quotations before the whitespace.

```
"(?<=\".*?\")\s+"
```

This doesn't work as look-behinds have to be constant size.

EDIT: Turns out look-around is immediate, while I want this to happen where it's immediate or after many characters.

I'd like to be able to use vim's \zs \ze (or some equivalent to):

```
"\".*?\".*\zs\s\ze"
```

I only want to match the white-space afterall.

EDIT 2:
I've solved not the question but the issue I was trying to solve.
If any are interested:

```
'("[^"]*")\s+|([^" ]+)\s+|("[^"]*")$|([^" ]+)$'
```

This can probably be reduced a fair bit but it works.
re.split returns an array of Nones, empty strings and the strings I actually want so I just have to remove the first two and sorted.

Comment: It depends... How do you want to handle question marks inside quotation marks?

Comment: Question marks should be treated like normal text, but I don't think they are going to show up in the text.

Comment: In Vim, you can't use `.*?`, the Vim equivalent is `.\{-}`

Comment: I'm not using Vim, I'm using Python's re. I was just saying I'd like to be able to use an equivalent to \zs and \ze

Answer (score 1):

What about `^[^\"]*(\"[^\"]*\"[^\"]*)*(\s+)`?

This is using `[^\"]*` for "any number of characters that are not quotation marks" to prevent `a "great" 42" monitor` from being matched in three possible ways (first to second quotation mark, first to third, or second to third).

So basically it says:

- 0 or more times non-quotation-marks
- 0 or more times a group consisting of

  - "
  - 0 or more non-quotation-marks
  - "
  - 0 or more non-quotation-marks
- then one or more spaces